# How to change position of list using the onkey function in python

Tags: python, list, turtle-graphics

I want to change the shape of turtle with a list that has been made `shapes = ["square", "triangle", "circle"]` by using the onkey function. What I mean is whenever I press a button, for example h, how would I make it so that it goes through each of the shapes whenever I press h. I will be using the `turtle.shape ()` function to achieve this.

What I have done so far is created a list of shapes but I have no idea on how to achieve the next thing that I want to achieve.

```
  def turtle1 ():
   shapes = ["square", "triangle", "circle", "pentagon", "star", "octagon"]
   shapeiter = itertools.cycle(shapes)
   next(shapeiter)
   1
   shape(next(shapeiter))
   next(shapeiter)
   2
   shape(next(shapeiter))
   next(shapeiter)
   3
   shape(next(shapeiter))
   next(shapeiter)
   4
   shape(next(shapeiter))
   next(shapeiter)
   5
   shape(next(shapeiter))
   next(shapeiter)
   6
   shape(next(shapeiter))


 onkey(turtle1, "h")
```

Answer (score 0):

[`itertools.cycle()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) will let you cycle through a sequence indefinitely.

```
>>> t = itertools.cycle((1, 2, 3))
>>> next(t)
1
>>> next(t)
2
>>> next(t)
3
>>> next(t)
1
>>> next(t)
2
```

Comment: Would I replace the numbers with the shapes?

Comment: You would replace the argument to the function with any sequence you want to cycle through, e.g. `shapeiter = itertools.cycle(shapes)`. Just make sure to only call the function once.

Comment: Ok lemme experiment with this and I'll post my findings.

Comment: I tried doing what is in the edited post but doesn't seem to work.

Comment: `next()` returns a value. You need to do something with that value.

Comment: Ok so after next (shapeiter)|1 would I go shape (shapes (1)) then next (shapeiter)|2 shape (shapes (2))?

Comment: No. You take the value returned by `next()` and pass it to `turtle.shape()`.

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to do that.

Comment: `turtle.shape(next(shapeiter))`

Comment: Ok so I did what you said and it cycles through the list but only stops at the one at the end.

Comment: It should never stop. That's what `itertools.cycle()` does. You need to call `next()` only once each time the key is pressed.

Comment: I reworte @Hayden's code using your `itertools.cycle()` approach to attempt to finally put this question to bed.  It works as expected but @Hayden's original lists of shapes isn't valid so it's been replaced by `turtle.getshapes()`.

Answer (score 0):

This question didn't seem to have proper closure so I'm going to attempt such.

Below is a rewrite using @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams' `itertools.cycle()`-based solution.  @Hayden's original code listed shapes that weren't necessarily valid, which might have caused his code to quit prematurely.  I've used `turtle.getshapes()` to obtain the valid shapes and I've also changed the window title to provide the shape name:

```
import turtle
import itertools

def reshape():
    turtle.shape(next(shape_iterator))

    turtle.title(turtle.shape())

screen = turtle.Screen()

shape_iterator = itertools.cycle(screen.getshapes())

screen.onkey(reshape, "h")

screen.listen()

reshape()

screen.mainloop()
```

Click on the window to make it active and then type 'h' to cycle through all the built-in turtle shapes.